# std::chrono time points, duration conversions, and fractional values

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono, g++-5

Say I time a task with the following:

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// ...do work here...
auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

The time that elapsed is:

```
auto elapsed = t2 - t1;
```

I'm a bit confused as to what units `duration` uses, and how to **correctly** convert it to seconds with fractional seconds.

If I do this:

```
std::cout << "count=" << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
```

...then I seem to get nanoseconds.  But if I do this instead:

```
const double secs = std::chrono::duration<double>(elapsed).count();
std::cout << "count=" << secs << std::endl;
```

...then it looks like I get the seconds and fractional seconds I was hoping to work with.

While this code works with the compiler I'm using, I worry that because I'm not specifying the units I want during the conversion of the duration, what I've done is implementation-specific and may not work as expected with a different compiler.  Is there a better or more explicit way to convert the duration to "seconds" (including the fractional part)?

Comment: Your conversion to double-based seconds is portable.  Here's a 1h long video tutorial on chrono that might help get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: @HowardHinnant The guy in that video looks familiar...  :)  Watching it now, thanks for the link.